# VSS to TFS migration

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe, vssconverter

I have migrated from VSS to TFS. But some of my team members have checked in some modifications to VSS again. How to migrate these changes to TFS again?

Comment: Did you use the VSS migration tool? IF so you should be able to run your migration script again and this will do an incremental update to TFS

Comment: I used VSS converter tool. Shall I run it again. Please confirm.

Comment: run it again, using the same machine and settings. When it runs it should ask you if you want to do an incremental migration. Say Yes. This will migrate the changes made by your team. Make VSS read only when you have finished to prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd:

- Use history on VSS to determine what files they have changed
- Get those changes into your VSS workspace, and check out the equivalent files in your TFS workspace
- Copy the changed (VSS) files over the ones in your TFS workspace
- Build, Test, Check-in to TFS
- Use the VSS Admin tool to revoke all write access to your SourceSafe code-base so it doesn't happen again.
- Get developers to uninstall VSS if it is no longer needed, so it doesn't happen again